# Multple Kentico projects in a single solution

Tags: kentico

As I'm in development on my 2nd and 3rd kentico sites, we're looking at code management. Our ideal solution is a single Kentico Solution, with individual CMS folders.

In theory this should be fine, but would there be any potential issues, especially regarding versioning? Right now, I have one site on 9 hotfix 5, and the other two on 9 hotfix 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a development standpoint you should be fine.  When performing upgrades, hotfixes or new installs this may cause problems because the KIT looks at the actual .sln file or the actual root directory the .sln file is in.

What I would do is setup a solution like this and try out an upgrade and a hotfix and some local development.

Comment: Thanks Brenden, that's what i'm setting up right now. Two sample sites, and then see what breaks.

Comment: Reviewing some of the other comments @MarkHandy if you decide to rename the CMS directory, it will work for development but will cause problems when running the KIT to upgrade or apply hotfixes.  So although it works for development scenarios it won't work for using any tools to perform the upgrade.  You'll need to perform those manually and they might not even work but it's worth a try.  Might I ask why you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There would be a problem with applying hotfixes and upgrades. They both count on the fact that the web project is in a folder called `CMS`... So you would introduce some manual steps in those processes. Conclusion - don't do that.

Comment: I've rename CMS to reflect the specific site. I'm assuming the will work, but won't really know until I try.

Comment: I agree - the disadvantages greatly outweigh advantages (if there are any)

Comment: @MarkHandy it won't work automatically. you'll have to follow the steps for the [remote installation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Hotfix+Instructions+-+Kentico+9#HotfixInstructions-Kentico9-Remoteinstallation.1) and perform the hotfixing manually...

Answer (score 2):

I certainly agree with @rocky. I'd question what advantages you expect from this scenario? I assume the 3 sites are entirely independent of each other (don't share a database) so keep them as separate Kentico solutions. They're separate applications so why share a solution file? This'll make your life so much easier. A solution should only contain multiple applications if they're intrinsically linked.

If it's because you have custom code that you'd like to share between the instances, best to move that code into custom assemblies and share those in your various solutions. If necessary your separate solutions could include the same files as per this folder structure overview below. This way your hotfixes and upgrades remain entirely localised and you remain safe from harm!

- Development

  - Kentico 1

    - CMSApp.sln
    - CMS

      - CMSApp_AppCode.csproj

        - *References My.CustomBusinessLogic and My.SharedCore*
  - Kentico 2

    - CMSApp.sln
    - CMS

      - CMSApp_AppCode.csproj

        - *References My.SharedCore only*
  - Kentico 3

    - CMSApp.sln
    - CMS

      - CMSApp_AppCode.csproj
  - My.CustomBusinessLogic

    - My.CustomBusinessLogic.csp
  - My.SharedCore

    - My.SharedCore.csproj